# Xamarin Android Image cropper

Tags: android, image, xamarin, cropper

I've been looking into this image cropper that I found https://github.com/mikescandy/Xamarin-Cropper

I used it on my Android Studio project and it works but I don't know how to implement it on Xamarin Visual Studio for Android. I'm learning both platforms to increase my knowledge but I'm having a hard time implementing the cropper.

I checked the guide that was included there but it's for Android Studio and still, I can't make it work. The sample that was included makes me lost.

Anyone know how to implement it properly? I manage to insert the CropView in my XAML file and initialize it but I'm just lost. Please help me, I want to learn.

EDIT: I still cant figure it out, anyone can help me?

Comment: `XAML` ? Are you using Xamarin.Forms for your UI, or native Android layouts via a `Xamarin.Android` application project as `CropImageView` is Android specific. If you are using Forms, you could embed it into your XAML, but you would need to use something else for iOS and/or UWP. https://blog.xamarin.com/embedding-native-controls-into-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm using Android only. How would I implement it? There's "Using View" and "Using Activity" in the page I linked and I have no clue on how to do it. I tried looking for other  samples but I couldn't find any

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the following plugin for it.**

https://github.com/mikescandy/Xamarin-Cropper

it is well documented on Github as well.

> Note: This is for Xamarin Mono Android